# Clueless About a (Possible) Android Memory Leak

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, bitmap, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I’ve been facing some annoying `OutOfMemoryErrors`, even after making sure that all my Bitmaps are properly scaled etc. In fact, the issue doesn’t seem to be related to Bitmaps at all, but I may be wrong.

For testing and error-isolation purposes, I’ve been switching between two activities (let’s call them Main and List) using my Navigation Drawer (not using the back button). I can see in the DDMS that the allocated memory increases around 180 KB every time I return.

I’ve done memory dumps and used eclipse MAT to analyze 3 different points in time:

[image: Screen1]

[image: Screen2]

[image: Screen3]

I suspect a memory leak but I can’t really find out its cause. According to the memory dumps, it looks like it’s the “Remainder” and `java.lang.FinalizerReference` that keep increasing. The user in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13676576/memory-leak-caused-by-java-lang-ref-finalizerreference) also has a lot of `FinalizerReferences` in his memory dump, but the answer isn't quite clear.

The Leak Suspects Report I made in the last point in time isn’t very helpful as it suspects of `android.content.res.Resources` and `android.graphics.Bitmap` which don’t seem to be growing over time:

[image: Screen3LeakReport]

In one of the reports (sadly, not present here) I've seen 13 instances of `android.widget.ListView` pointed as a potential leak suspect.

These memory increases happen with any transition between activities (not just the Main and List I used in this example).

How can I find the (non-obvious?) memory leak? I’ve been scratching my head for a long time so any help and tips would be great.

### EDIT:

- Bitmaps (@OrhanC1): I've commented any `Bitmap` instantiations in the two activities mentioned above and the memory still increases. The memory dump still shows some bitmaps but I believe they're related to resources and not actual bitmaps allocated by me.
- Regarding custom fonts (@erakitin): I'm using them, but I'm keeping a single instance of each `Typeface` in my `Application` context (`public class MyApp extends Application`) using a singleton. I've tried commenting any references to the fonts in the two activities mentioned above and the memory still increases.
- I don't think I'm leaking the `Context` (@DigCamara): I don't hold any static references inside these two Activities, I'm using the `Application` context instead of the `Activity`'s except in an adapter. If I stay in the same `Activity` and do some screen rotations, the memory doesn't increase.
- Based on @NickT's comment: I can see I have many instances of both activities. Could these memory increases be *just the result of an increase in the number of activities of the back stack and not a memory leak* (I though the OS dealt with that, [apparently not](http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html))? If I use the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT` intent flag then the memory only increases until all different activities have been instantiated (once). Useful for this matter: [Android not killing activities from stack when memory is low](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616575/android-not-killing-activities-from-stack-when-memory-is-low).

Comment: Are you starting a new version of the activity each transition (rather than reusing a background instance)? Perhaps my answer to this may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835398/

Comment: What happens when you remove the bitmaps completely?

Comment: Without seeing your code we can only guess what's happening.

Comment: @Squonk - I agree with you but in this particular case its complicated: as I don't really know the source of the problem I'd have to post a very large amount of code.

Comment: @OrhanC1 - I've commented any Bitmap creation in the two exemplified activities. Memory still increases.

Comment: @user1987392 Are you using custom fonts in your application? I had the same issue before I start "caching" typefaces created from assets.

Comment: @erakitin - I was going to write about that in the question but didn't want to make it any longer: I use custom fonts and I keep the instantiated Typefaces in my Application class, using the Singleton pattern. I'm assuming that's the proper way to do it (?)

Comment: I use custom fonts in navigation drawer and all bitmaps had leaked. Following answer can help me solve this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16902532/1049475 Try to remove using custom fonts and test again.

Comment: Even though the FontCache looks like a better way of doing it, I already manage my fonts by keeping a single instance in my Application context. I've also commented out the Typeface usage between the two activities, memory still increases.

Comment: From what you posted, it's likely that you're actually leaking the Context. Take a look at this blogpost: http://www.curious-creature.org/2008/12/18/avoid-memory-leaks-on-android/

Comment: check out this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355064/is-memory-leak-why-java-lang-ref-finalizer-eat-so-much-memory
It sounds like there are a few cases where they are using lots of objects that override the object.finalize() method and the thread that processes the queue to finalize these objects can't keep up.

Comment: Also if you have lots of redundant activities on the stack maybe try calling finish() on the activity when sending it to a new one to remove it from the stack using       startActivityForResult(myIntent, CLOSE_THIS_ACTIVITY);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) { super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
  if(requestCode == CLOSE_THIS_ACTIVITY)
  {
   finish();
  }
 }

Comment: Since you're using MAT anyway, how about you do some OQL queries? You have a leak suspect - the ListView. Do a heap.livepaths for them, and try to find any spurious paths that shouldn't be there or you are not cleaning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like the reason why the `Remainder` is growing is the growth of the number of `Activity` instances in the back stack (e.g. 13 instances of the "List" `Activity` + 13 instances of the "Main" `Activity`).

I've changed my Navigation Drawer so that when the user clicks the "Home" button (which takes him to the App's "Dashboard") I set the `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flags: the Activity is re-used and the back stack is cleared ([as recommended by the Android guidelines, actually](https://developer.android.com/training/design-navigation/ancestral-temporal.html)). In fact, I should have done this already as I don't want several instances of the Dashboard ("Home") activity to be created.

By doing this I can see that the Activities are destroyed and allocated heap size (including the "`Remaining`" slice) decreases:

[image: Fixing problem with increasing memory.]

While fixing this, I also noticed that one of my Activities and a Bitmap used by it were not being destroyed, even if the back stack had been cleared (leak). After analysing with MAT I concluded that the source of this sub-problem was a reference to an `ImageView` that I kept in the `Activity`. By adding this code to the `onStop()` method, I've managed to get both the activity and `Bitmap` to be destroyed:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImage );
    if(myImage .getDrawable() != null)
        myImage.getDrawable().setCallback(null);

    RoundedImageView roundImage = (RoundedImageView) findViewById(R.id.roundImage); // a custom View
    if(roundImage.getDrawable() != null)
        roundImage.getDrawable().setCallback(null);


}
```

I then generalized all my `Activity` and `FragmentActivity` so that they call `unbindDrawables(View view)` in `onDestroy()`:

```
private void unbindDrawables(View view)
{
    if (view.getBackground() != null)
    {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup && !(view instanceof AdapterView))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++)
        {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
    }
}
```

Thanks to @NickT for pointing me in the right direction.