# Normal memory consumption for an android application?

Tags: android, memory, stack, destroy

My applications memory consumption seems rather high when switching between activities. I quick explanation is that I have an ActivityA that is singleTop and is basically the home screen, you select an item in a list and it takes you to ActivityB which is a more detailed version of the list item. You then press back and it finishes the activity returning to ActivityA. Both activities are quite rich in controls and have high quality images scattered around, but there's definitely something not right here.

I have drawn a quick diagram to show the lifecycle:

[image]

As you can see when the app first starts it is at 34MB, after selecting a list item it goes up 2.5MB, then when I press back it goes up again.. this will continue to happen whilst going back and forth. The first thing I need to establish is whether or not this is normal behavior for an application? If this is not the case I clearly have some work to do in releasing some resources, the issue is, what?

In my onDestroy() of ActivityB I unregister from all my receivers, I call finish() on anything I use and have even tried setting everything to null but still no change! I use no special flags when starting ActivityB or finishing it, could that be part of the problem? The history of the stack is sticking around maybe?

**EDIT:**

I use SceneTransitionAnimation to move an image between the two activities, when I turn this off it goes up 0.5MB each time I go from A to B and 0.01MB when I go from B to A. I guess I should ask the question of how the much bigger increase can be avoided whilst still using SceneTransitionAnimations??

Comment: try these http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/performance/index.html

Comment: Using Bitmaps? If so, check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23652549/clueless-about-a-possible-android-memory-leak

Comment: I do use bitmaps, but I've already tried that solution everywhere and it doesnt make a shred of difference